# Equality operator in dart?

Tags: dart

So I have this code:

```
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';
class ZipItem<I1, I2>{
  I1 item1;
  I2 item2;

  ZipItem(this.item1, this.item2);
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      (other is ZipItem &&
          item1 == other.item1 &&
          item2 == other.item2);

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(item1.hashCode, item2.hashCode);
```

and when I run a test like `expect(ZipItem('a', 1), ZipItem('a', 1));`, it passes. However if I try to run a test like this:

```
 expect(ZipItem([1,2,3], ['a','b','c']), 
 equals(ZipItem([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])));
```

it fails, and I can't figure out why. I think it has to do with the items being iterable but I am not sure. If anybody can help me out I'd appreciate it :).

Comment: [2] does not equal [2].  And that's just the beginning. :)

Comment: I see, lists don't equal each other in dart using the == operator. I found a work around by using item1.toString() == other.item1.toSting(). Is this a robust solution for a workaround or is it vulnerable to other things I may not know about? @RandalSchwartz

Comment: It's a pretty bad solution.  Look at listEquals in the foundation library (part of the flutter sdk).

Comment: The issue is thought that, at least for this specific class, I need to write it using generic types, so unfortunately listEquals doesn't work as I would be bound to Lists, same with mapsEquals, etc. I could create a long switch case that checks for different types and intercepts them with their proper equality function. Though I don't know if that's any better than calling .toString() and checking equality of the two objects that way.

Comment: See Deep Equality in package collection

Comment: *Anything* is better than calling `toString`, even just accepting `false`, since `[1].toString() == ["1"].toString()`. False positives in equality are strictly worse than lack of equality between similar objects. The latter you can work around. The former causes subtle and unexpected bugs. It makes the `hashCode` break contract too, since equal values should have equal hash codes. (But yes, `DeepEquality` from `package:collection` would be my recommendation too.)

Comment: I see that makes sense, don't know why I didn't think of that must be the lack of sleep. Thanks I'll check out DeepEquality in collection

Answer (score 0):

The [`collection` package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection#equality) has many utilities for calculating collection equality (and hash codes).

When dealing with generic types as you are, [`DeepCollectionEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/DeepCollectionEquality-class.html) is most appropriate, as it uses the right equality checking behavior based on the types of the objects provided to it.

Alternatively, you may find the [`equatable` package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) useful. It aims to simplify the process of implementing `==` and `hashCode`, and implements collection equality out-of-the-box.